# Is there a SQL function to convert Decimal date into Real date

Tags: r, postgresql, statistics

I'm unable to decipher the applicate_date on the dataset picture attached below. The date is in decimals and I tried the julian date function but it didn't help. My desired outcome is that the entire column should be in the format mm/dd/yyyy between 1st July 2010 and 31st June 2011.
Please find database attached.    [Dataset picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNqjz.png)

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: So what date is 14838.0 supposed to be?

Comment: Perhaps something like: `as.Date(14838, origin = "1970-01-01")`, depends on the exact origin.

Comment: Using hint from @MartinGal: `select '1970-01-01'::date + '14838 days'::interval; 2010-08-17 00:00:00` Does that match the actual date?